# Import specific data from txt file to specific column in excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, vba

I want to import specific data from a .txt file to put them into an excel sheet, which is continuously updated (ie) the script needs to put the data on the next available line on the sheet.

Part of my .txt file

```
 **Processor Scientific Analysis
    Analysing...
    Aggregated Score : 5.99GFLOPS
    Result ID : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 3965U @ 2.20GHz (2C 2.21GHz, 2x 256kB L2, 2MB L3)
    Speed : 2208MHz
    Capacity : 2Unit(s)
    Finished Successfully : Yes**
```

On my excel sheet, I just need the value of the aggregate score (5.99) to be put on the correct column.

Help?

Comment: Help with what? With reading of file? With finding for a specific data? With identifying a next available line? Are you hire someone?

Comment: Hi, this is not a code for me site, please read How to Ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @CommonSense no I am not hiring someone. I need help for taking the value 5.99 that is in the .txt file and put on the correct collum on the excel and on the correct line (the next one available)

Comment: @TimWilkinson  of course, this is not a code. This is a part of my .txt file

Comment: It's also not so trivial task if your data is continuously updating. Start with [`fso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx), learn how to control a [`TextStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724(v=vs.60).aspx) object, how to read it line-by-line, how to wait at the end of the stream for more (spoiler, it's looks like impossible task, because there's no threading in VBA, hence you need to think how often you will check your stream) . After that go for a next part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific about "the next available line on a sheet".  Are you putting it in the first column?

The following function will return the text that follows the string `Aggregated Score :`

Run it by from your sub by something like:

`gGlopString = getString()`

The following code itterates through the text in each line of the file stream.  First 19 chars (the result of Len(testStr) matches teststr, it puts the remaining text (all the chars to the right of the result of the Length of the line of text - the length of testStr) of the string into a variable which ends up being returned by your function.

```
Public Function getString() As String
        Dim myFSO As New FileSystemObject
        Dim path As String
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim testStr as String

        path = "C:\PATH\TO\FILE"
        fileName = "FILENAME.txt"
        testStr = "Aggregated Score : "
        i = 0
        x = 0

        Set fso = myFSO.OpenTextFile(path + fileName)
        Do Until fso.AtEndOfStream
            txt = fso.ReadLine
            For x = 1 To Len(txt)
                If Mid(txt, x, Len(testStr)) = testStr Then
                    resultStr = Right(txt, (Len(txt)-Len(testStr))
                    ' Enter your code to move resultStr into the cell you want
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        getString = resultStr

        fso.Close

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This will read the specified text file and put the value found between "Aggregated Score" and "GFLOPS" into the **active cell** on the worksheet:

```
Function GetAggregatedScore() As Double

    Const txtFileName = "C:\yourPath\yourFileName.txt"
    Dim txt As String, tStart As Long, tStop As Long

    Open txtFileName For Input As #1
    txt = Input(LOF(1), #1)
    Close #1

    tStart = InStr(1, txt, "Aggregated Score :", vbTextCompare) + Len("Aggregated Score :")
    tStop = InStr(tStart, txt, "GFLOPS", vbTextCompare)

    GetAggregatedScore = Val(Mid(txt, tStart, tStop - tStart))

End Function
```

You could add a button with that code to your worksheet and click it when you need the number from the current version of the file (assuming the file will always have the same name, or that you update the name as needed).